# get error when tried to access log from UI

Tags: airflow

I installed airflow 2.7.3. and I'm using localExcutor. I tried to access task log, but got error below.

*** Could not read served logs: Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.

is there any config missing?